# Identify grasshopper species

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

[image]I found this grasshopper on a house door in central Italy. It did not move for the whole day. I can tell it's a grasshopper, however I am unable to determine the exact species.

Size: ca. 6cm

Feel free to ask if you need any more information / details.

Comment: Identifications questions should include: 1) one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible) — photos must be uploaded (not links); and 2) habitat information. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. Not in particular that without at least one picture or a **very** detailed description this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had uploaded the picture. This is the only one I have as I am no longer there.

Comment: Unlikely to get a full ID from that photo - too dim to make out markings and not enough views to get morphologic features.